# Unwrapping a formula?

Tags: ruby

In my ongoing quest to learn ruby by doing training exercises I came across an extra credit question that basically wants me to unwrap this formula:

```
what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))
```

My question is I am a little stuck on this part. I understand for example that `add(age, subtract` would be the same as `age + subtract`, but after that I just become lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from the inside and work out.

Divide iq by 2.  Multiply that by weight.  Subtract that from height.  Add that to age.

In general, with nested parentheses, you always start from the innermost.

Comment: what = (iq / 2 * weight - height + age)

Comment: what = (iq / 2 * weight - height + age)
This is what I managed to come up with but its not giving me the answer due to it having the wrong order, I want it to divide first, then multiply, then subtract and add, the answer it gives me tells me its not going in that order.

Comment: The purpose of parentheses in this type of formula is to manage the order that the operations occur, if you need that to be different than standard order (standard order is multiplication and division, left to right, and then addition and subtraction, left to right).

Comment: But also, I don't think you want to subtract height; I think you want to subtract FROM height.  Don't you?

Answer (score 6):

Keep going, but work from the inside-out instead--what's `divide(iq, 2)`? Use that as the second argument for `multiply`, and so on.